# Heroku Scheduler Add On UTC Timezone cannot be changed

Tags: heroku, timezone, scheduler, heroku-addon

I have been working on a project that needs to complete a task at a certain time everyday. I am using the 'free' Heroku Scheduler Add-on and the task is completed, but the problem is that it is not completed in the exact time I set for it to be completed because the scheduler has a default UTC time zone that won't change even if the time zone for app is changed. Also, if there are daylight savings time changes (since it is a UTC time zone) it won't recognize that change and will do the task at the wrong time. Is there anyway to change the time zone to my desired one which would be in US/Eastern?

I already looked at [Heroku Scheduler timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429069/heroku-scheduler-timezone/32432167) and it seems to be the online place with any information on it, but there are no instructions on how to fix the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[Heroku Scheduler Task Setup Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC6Q4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not change Heroku Scheduler Add-on  time zone, only solution is to move the time checking logic to your app, for example you have to run it each hour, then in your app/command check if the time is the correct time, if it's not exist the app until current time meet your requirements